# Writing a MySql function within PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, syntax

I have this following function in my php script:

```
$fcnsql = "CREATE FUNCTION CUST_ORDER(index INT, weekday INT, curweekday INT, endtime TIME, curtime    TIME)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE custom_weekday INT;
IF (weekday=curweekday AND curtime>endtime) THEN
SET custom_weekday = index+7;
ELSE
SET custom_weekday = index;
END IF;
RETURN custom_weekday;
END";

$test=mysql_query($fcnsql) or die (mysql_error());
```

What I get as output is that I have a SQL syntax error. Any idea what is wrong?

Some things I think could be the problem:

1. I'm not sure if its the correct syntax for having TIME variables as parameters in my function.
2. I see on some sample code online that before a mysql function, there is a line "delimiter $$"--I'm not sure what this is for and how/whether I need to use it.

I'm very new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why are you creating a MySQL function using PHP?  Why not create the MySQL function int the console, and then *call* the function using PHP code?

Comment: what is the error you get??

Comment: How do I do that? As I said, I'm very new to this. I don't think that would fix the syntax error, would it? I've done my best with looking up online resources, but after much troubleshooting I still cannot get it to work.

Comment: The error that I get is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index INT, weekday INT, curweekday INT, endtime TIME, curtime TIME) RETURNS IN' at line 1"

Comment: `index` is a keyword (see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)). You can't use it as a parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** @Pang called it - index is a reserved word. If you don't want to change the name, then wrap it in backticks:

```
`index`
```

I'll keep the rest of my waffle in place, as you weren't sure about DELIMITER. :)

--

The error is probably that you haven't set the DELIMITER, as you noticed in some examples. Add these to the top and bottom of your function:

```
$fcnsql = "
DELIMITER #
CREATE FUNCTION CUST_ORDER2(`index` INT, weekday INT, curweekday INT, endtime TIME, curtime TIME) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE custom_weekday INT;
IF (weekday=curweekday AND curtime>endtime) THEN
    SET custom_weekday = `index`+7;
ELSE
    SET custom_weekday = `index`;
END IF;
RETURN custom_weekday;
END;
#
DELIMITER ;
";
```

The reason is that ";" is MySQLs default delimiter (i.e. the thing that tells MySQL it has hit the end of a statement). Your function's statements needs delimiters, but whilst MySQL is saving it, you don't want MySQL to think it's found the end of a statement and stop processing the function. So you change the delimiter to a character that you aren't using in the function, then change it back again afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I seems I'm still getting a similar syntax error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER # CREATE FUNCTION CUST_ORDER(ind INT, weekday INT, curweekday INT, e' at line 1

Comment: EDIT: I tried to set DELIMITER # in a separate mysql query first and that seemed to fix my previous problem (since mysql can only do one query at a time). However, I'm now getting this error instead: "Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted" Would you know how to troubleshoot this one? Thanks

Comment: Have you recently upgraded mysql? I've got no direct experience of this error, but the google-machine hints at a bad / incomplete upgrade of mysql being the common cause of this error